# Skip hidden folders in .bat scripts

Tags: windows, batch

I am trying to find a way to get a listing of all files, without hidden directories.  I have tried several variations of something like this:

```
dir  /b  /s  /a:-h  z:\  >toc-z.txt
```

but this only skips over hidden files.  I need a listing which excludes all hidden folders, including files and sub-folders of these hidden folders.

Is there any way I can skip parsing and listing of hidden folders?

Comment: Not with a simple *dir* command, since it will still display files and folders which are inside the hidden folders but aren't hidden themselves. It might be simpler to do this using PowerShell instead of batch, or use a better shell such as [Take Command](http://jpsoft.com/tccle-cmd-replacement.html), whose [*dir* command](http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?dir.htm) supports extended options such as "/Nd: Skip hidden directories (when used with /S)".

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hackish, but you could probably use the `xcopy` command with the `/l` and `/s` (or perhaps the `/e`) options. The key is the `/l` option which tells it to display a list of files that are *to be* copied rather than making any copies. By default, `xcopy` does not copy hidden or system files so they will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long command, but it works, and it is fairly fast :-)

Here it is as a long one liner for the command line

```
>toc-z.txt ((for %F in ("z:\*") do @echo %F)&for /f "delims=" %D in ('dir /s /ad-h-l /b z:\*^|sort') do @for %F in ("%D\*") do @echo %F)
```

Here it is as a batch file

```
@echo off
>toc-z.txt (
  for %%F in ("z:\*") do @echo %%F
  for /f "delims=" %%D in (
    'dir /s /ad-h-l /b z:\*^|sort'
  ) do for %%F in ("%%D\*") do echo %%F
)
```

Comment: EDIT - major fixes: 1) added log, 2) added root files, 3) made root z:\ 4) eliminate reparse points, 5) sort output to be depth first